# Contenteditable="true" not working properly with jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, contenteditable

For some reason I can't add space between letters when I have contenteditable on jQuery UI tabs. You can add text and delete but I cant add white-space. See here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByEEQe

Click on the text in the tabs and try adding space.

```
<a href='#tab-2'><span contenteditable="true">THIS ALSO IS TAB</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI Tabs listens to `keydown` event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/tabs.js#L191):

```
_tabKeydown: function( event ) {
    // ...
    case $.ui.keyCode.SPACE:
        // Activate only, no collapsing
        event.preventDefault();
    // ...
```

As you can see it calls the `preventDefault` method of the `event` object if the space key is pressed. You can listen to `keydown` event and stop the propagation of the event:

```
$("#sidebar-canvas-content")
   .tabs()
   .find('.sidebar-tab span[contenteditable]').on('keydown', function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();    
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a workaround but adding (contenteditable = true) w/jQuery solves the problem.

```
$("#sidebar-canvas-content").attr('contenteditable','true');
```